# In which phase "Initial" blocks are executed?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have an interface signal, that I initialize in an `initial` block in my top module.
In a test, I want to randomize its value by the mean of `randomize()`. But the problem I don't know in which phase I should call the randomization function.
Would calling `randomize()` at `build()` phase be correct ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you call `uvm_pkg::run_test()` from an `initial` block in a module, `run_test()` will start all the UVM phases after a delta delay. That means all other `initial` block have a chance to execute before any UVM phase begin.

The UVM recommends that you not drive any signals until the start_of_simulation() phase or later.